# replacement for cast and collect in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-objects

I want to convert the below statement into normal query.

SELECT CAST(COLLECT(warehouse_name ORDER BY warehouse_name)
AS warehouse_name_t) "Warehouses"
FROM warehouses;

How to do this?

I tried some of the things but could not succeed. Please help.

Comment: The current query will give you a collection of names, as whatever data type `warehouse_name_t` is - e.g. a nested table. What do you mean by a 'normal query' - what output do you want instead? If you still want a collection then explain what the problem is with this code. If you don't want a collection then just query the column from the table directly - `select warehouse_name from warehouses`.

Comment: `CAST` and `COLLECT` are standard built-in Oracle function so your query is a "normal query". Please [edit] the question to explain what your expected outcome would be if you do not use `CAST` and `COLLECT`?

Comment: When you write *I've tried <smt> but **it doesn't work/with no success*** please clarify the meaning of "doesn't work" or "no success": any error messages, unexpected result or something that makes you think it is not what you expect

Answer (score 2):

If you want ANSI SQL and do not want a collection but want the values as rows:

```sql
SELECT warehouse_name 
FROM   Warehouses
ORDER BY warehouse_name
```

If you want to aggregate the rows into a single row and want a delimited single string then use `LISTAGG`:

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(warehouse_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY warehouse_name)
         AS warehouses
FROM   Warehouses
```

If you want a collection data-type then `CAST` and `COLLECT` are standard built-in functions and are exactly what you should be using:

```sql
SELECT CAST(
         COLLECT(warehouse_name ORDER BY warehouse_name)
         AS warehouse_name_t
       ) AS Warehouses
FROM   warehouses;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=508509218c18af3d19be91df14a6d339)*